# What does "シュパシュパー" mean?

Tags: onomatopoeia

I struggle looking up onomatopoeia, I tried, but the closest I found "dry," but in context, it makes no sense.

Context:
わーい！　あたしも司くんも、シュパシュパーって
忍者さんみたいに動くよ！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It describes a swift and sharp movement, exactly like our image of a ninja. If you could find nothing with シュパシュパ, perhaps you can try image search for "シュパパパ" instead, which is an even quicker variant of this.